# Generate code from wavelet toolbox in matlab

Tags: matlab, wavelet

I am using the wavelet toolbox to do a 1D continuous wavelet ransform and have got some really nice results.

Do I now have to write all the code in matlab or is there a way to generate code from the toolbox?

for example:

[image: wavelet]

Can I generate the code used to get this output?

It used to be File --> generate

e.g. 
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ug/generating-matlab-code-for-1-d-wavelet-packet-denoising-and-compression.html

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at free libraries like [WaveLab](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~wavelab/WaveLab701.html) before you take on the task of programming this from scratch. These algorithms were all developed in the 1990s and most of them are implemented there.

Comment: @alle_meiji thanks a lot, cool links.  Nevertheless would like to reiterate I have the wavelet toolbox and so can use commands like cwt, etc.  I am wondering if it is possible to generate the code from the toolbox rather than have to rewrite it all?

Comment: Hi -- sorry to have taken a while to respond. The example shows you which code is generated -- you can just use that. And the functions called in the generated code are in the wavelet toolbox -- if you have that installed then you don't need to write those yourself. I thought you were looking for an alternative to the wavelet toolbox. Otherwise it's all there!

Comment: thanks for getting back.  I need to write the code, it is done in the toolbox and there used to be an option to generate the equivalent toolbox output automatically in code, seems to be gone....